# Is it possible to create a path which consist of an environment variable + the filename

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, powershell-3.0

I want to copy an .exe file to `/App/Data/Local/Temp` and run the exe afterwards. Instead of adding the full, static filepath i would like to use `$env:TEMP` to have no dependency to the user account inside the ps. Based of `$env:TEMP` + the .exe file i tried to create a new variable `$LocalInstall` which i could use later inside the ps but it seems not to work.

```
$LocalInstallFile=$env:TEMP."\Agent.exe"
```

Later `$LocalInstallFile` should be used to run the installation with installation properties

```
Invoke-Expression "$LocalInstallFile /DIR=c:\"
```

Could i instead also use

```
Invoke-Expression "$env:TEMP\Agent.exe"
```

Comment: Did you try the last line? It should work fine...

Comment: true, it works. i just wonder why i get different paths for $env:TEMP when i run it from Powershell ISE or Powershell  (AppData/Local/Temp) (AppData/Local/Temp/1)? that why it didn´t worked

Comment: You shouldn't get different results unless you've modified it like `$env:temp += "\1"` (would only modify it in that console/process). Can't reproduce it

Comment: i didn´t expect it as well. seems to be related to the VM, altough i didnt modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
$LocalInstallFile=$env:TEMP."\Agent.exe"
```

will expand the `$env:TEMP` environment variable and then try to invoke the property called "\Agent.exe" on the string object which, of course, doesn't exist, so `$LocalInstallFile` is null. Instead, create the string like this:

```
$LocalInstallFile="$env:TEMP\Agent.exe"
```

Comment: thank you it works. is this the common practice how to format a string or is there also an other preferred method?  if i later use the variable $LocalnstallFile to run the .exe do i need to force it with an operator (&)